# Поиск по вхождению строки в django + haystack + Whoosh

Tags: python, django

Имеется некая модель. В ней хранятся названия фильмов. Вот класс индекса:

```
from haystack import indexes
from kino.films.models import Films

class FilmsIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    rusname = indexes.CharField(model_attr='rusname')
    origname = indexes.CharField(model_attr='origname')
    year = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='year')

    def get_model(self):
        return Films
```

Индекс создаётся и всё почти работает, но не совсем так как надо. Запрос вида

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(content='avatar')
```

возвращает то, что нужно, а вида

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(content='avat')
```

не возвращает ничего. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: обновил ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего. А точнее вы все делаете правильно. Сам на этом накололся, когда делал через хайстэк автокомплит в поиске.
Whoosh просто "полнотекстовый" поиск с минимальной морфологией. Для поиска вхождений вам надо пользоваться классическим like'ом.

**UPDATE**
Каюсь, я вас обманул. Решил все-таки нагуглить, чтобы не ударить в грязь лицом. И вот что нашлось.
У хайстэка есть специальный метод `autocomplete` как раз для этого.

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from myapp.models import Note

class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')
    # We add this for autocomplete.
    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='content')

    def get_model(self):
        return Note

    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return Note.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

И собственно сам поиск

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto='old')
# Result match things like 'goldfish', 'cuckold' & 'older'.
```

[Источник](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Как я понял фишка в использовании EdgeNgramField(). А если поиск по нескольким столбцам, то придётся наверное расписывать большую портянку:

    SearchQuerySet().filter(content_auto1='old').filter(content_auto2='old')...

Comment: Да в вашем случае, надо использовать `filter()`, а не `autocomplete()`. По идее он должен работать как и нативный фильтр. т.е. конструкция должна быть более простой

    SearchQuerySet().filter(
                         content_auto1='old', 
                         content_auto2='old'
                     )